# Searching for "OR" in solr

Tags: solr

since the word or is a boolean operator for search, what is the best way to allow searching for the postal abbreviation for Oregon (OR) in solr?

Comment: may not be ideal, but putting the word into quotes and removing it from the stopwords.txt file in conf will work

Answer (score 2):

you could add an "+" before the "OR" or even putting it in quotes, as Ruth said.